# combining the actions of a tooltip with that of a modal window

Tags: tooltip, qtip, modal-window

I have a component of my site that is jQuery. I would like to use like a tool tip to walk the end user through the process of navigating this component. I have tried to modify the qtip plugin to do this. A link will be clicked that will bring up the 1st tooltip which will contain a link taking the user to the next tool tip. I was able to find a modal window, that allows me to do this, however I was unable to figure out how to have the window pop up in a specific place like the tool tip. I was also unable to close the previous window when the next one opened.

Update:

Found the solution. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/advanced/#stepbystep The answer was burried the whole time! :)